# Refer to a determinate created button

Tags: vb.net

So In my program I’ve putted a flowlayourpanel and with a button I add to the layout infinite new buttons
(button.name = “button” + i.tostring) [i = i + 1]
With another button I want to hide the button with the i=3 so button3.hide(), but it doesn’t work beacause it doesn’t exist yet so How can I refer to the button created when the i was 3?

Answer (score 0):

`Name` is a property of the `Control` class so every control has that property. That doesn't mean that it needs to be set though, so some controls don't have a name. When you add a control to your form in the designer, what happens is that the `Name` property is set AND a field is declared with that name. That's why, if you name a `Button` control `Button1`, you are able to use the field `Button1` to refer to it.

When you create controls at run time, of course there is no field dedicated to that control so of course you can use such a dedicated field to refer to it. It's up to you to get a reference to that control from wherever you put it when you created it. Where that is is up to you but, if you added it to the `Controls` collection of a container, that is one option for getting it back. If you set the `Name` property, you can index the `Controls` collection with that name to get it, e.g.

```vb
Dim myButton = DirectCast(myFlowLayoutPanel.Controls("Button" & i), Button)
```

There may be other ways of getting that reference too. For instance, if you created your own `List(Of Button)` and set the `Tag` of each `Button` to the number, you could do this:

```vb
Dim myButton = myButtonList.Single(Function(btn) CInt(btn.Tag) = i)
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding your buttons to the FlowLayoutPanel you have correctly assinged a name. You can use this name to refer to the button as shown in Button2.Click.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i = 1 To 5
        Dim b As New Button
        b.Name = "btn" & i
        b.Text = "btn" & i
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls("btn3").Visible = False
End Sub
```